# Actionscript 3 - Fastest way to parse yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to a Date object?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have been trying to find a really fast way to parse yyyy-mm-dd [hh:mm:ss] into a Date object. Here are the 3 ways I have tried doing it and the times it takes each method to parse 50,000 date time strings.

Does anyone know any faster ways of doing this or tips to speed up the methods?

```
castMethod1 takes 3673 ms 
castMethod2 takes 3812 ms 
castMethod3 takes 3931 ms
```

Code:

```
private function castMethod1(dateString:String):Date {
    if ( dateString == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    var year:int = int(dateString.substr(0,4));
    var month:int = int(dateString.substr(5,2))-1;
    var day:int = int(dateString.substr(8,2));

    if ( year == 0 && month == 0 && day == 0 ) {
        return null;
    }

    if ( dateString.length == 10 ) {
        return new Date(year, month, day);
    }

    var hour:int = int(dateString.substr(11,2));
    var minute:int = int(dateString.substr(14,2));
    var second:int = int(dateString.substr(17,2));

    return new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
}
```

-

```
private function castMethod2(dateString:String):Date {
    if ( dateString == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    if ( dateString.indexOf("0000-00-00") != -1 ) {
        return null;
    }

    dateString = dateString.split("-").join("/");

    return new Date(Date.parse( dateString ));
}
```

-

```
private function castMethod3(dateString:String):Date {
    if ( dateString == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    var mainParts:Array = dateString.split(" ");
    var dateParts:Array = mainParts[0].split("-");

    if ( Number(dateParts[0])+Number(dateParts[1])+Number(dateParts[2]) == 0 ) {
        return null;
    }

    return new Date( Date.parse( dateParts.join("/")+(mainParts[1]?" "+mainParts[1]:" ") ) );
}
```

---

No, Date.parse will not handle dashes by default. And I need to return null for date time strings like `"0000-00-00"`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've been using the following snipplet to parse UTC date strings:

```
private function parseUTCDate( str : String ) : Date {
    var matches : Array = str.match(/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)Z/);

    var d : Date = new Date();

    d.setUTCFullYear(int(matches[1]), int(matches[2]) - 1, int(matches[3]));
    d.setUTCHours(int(matches[4]), int(matches[5]), int(matches[6]), 0);

    return d;
}
```

Just remove the time part and it should work fine for your needs:

```
private function parseDate( str : String ) : Date {
    var matches : Array = str.match(/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/);

    var d : Date = new Date();

    d.setUTCFullYear(int(matches[1]), int(matches[2]) - 1, int(matches[3]));

    return d;
}
```

<strike>No idea about the speed, I haven't been worried about that in my applications.</strike> 50K iterations in significantly less than a second on my machine.

Comment: Please tell us how long 50K iterations took for the 3 example functions, so we can put your "less than a second" in perspective.

Comment: I wonder will there be any extra performance if you replace var matches and d with const keyword.

Answer (score 5):

This was the fastest I could come up with after some fiddling:

```
private function castMethod4(dateString:String):Date {          
    if ( dateString == null ) 
        return null;    
    if ( dateString.length != 10 && dateString.length != 19) 
        return null;

    dateString = dateString.replace("-", "/");
    dateString = dateString.replace("-", "/");

    return new Date(Date.parse( dateString ));
}
```

I get 50k iterations in about 470ms for castMethod2() on my computer and 300 ms for my version (that's the same amount of work done in 63% of the time). I'd definitely say both are "Good enough" unless you're parsing silly amounts of dates.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing Date.Parse() doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Well then method 2 seems the best way:

```
private function castMethod2(dateString:String):Date {
    if ( dateString == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    if ( dateString.indexOf("0000-00-00") != -1 ) {
        return null;
    }

    dateString = dateString.split("-").join("/");

    return new Date(Date.parse( dateString ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Date.parse() does not accept all possible formats, we can preformat the passed dateString value using DateFormatter with formatString that Data.parse() can understand, e.g

```
// English formatter
var stringValue = "2010.10.06"
var dateCommonFormatter : DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
dateCommonFormatter.formatString = "YYYY/MM/DD";

var formattedStringValue : String = dateCommonFormatter.format(stringValue);                                
var dateFromString : Date = new Date(Date.parse(formattedStringValue));
```

Comment: Instead of performing these 2 steps, we could use [`DateFormatter.parseDateString()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html#parseDateString%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
var strDate:String = "2013-01-24 01:02:40";

function dateParser(s:String):Date{
    var regexp:RegExp = /(\d{4})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2}) (\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})/;
    var _result:Object = regexp.exec(s);

    return new Date(
        parseInt(_result[1]),
        parseInt(_result[2])-1,
        parseInt(_result[3]),
        parseInt(_result[4]),
        parseInt(_result[5]),
        parseInt(_result[6])
    );
}

var myDate:Date = dateParser(strDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation. Give this a try.

```
public static function dateToUtcTime(date:Date):String {
  var tmp:Array = new Array();
  var char:String;
  var output:String = '';

  // create format YYMMDDhhmmssZ
  // ensure 2 digits are used for each format entry, so 0x00 suffuxed at each byte

  tmp.push(date.secondsUTC);
  tmp.push(date.minutesUTC);
  tmp.push(date.hoursUTC);
  tmp.push(date.getUTCDate());
  tmp.push(date.getUTCMonth() + 1); // months 0-11
  tmp.push(date.getUTCFullYear() % 100);


  for(var i:int=0; i < 6/* 7 items pushed*/; ++i) {
    char = String(tmp.pop());
    trace("char: " + char);
    if(char.length < 2)
      output += "0";
    output += char;
  }

  output += 'Z';

  return output;
}
```