# How to check an UTC formatted date with a regular expression?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, datetime

As you know the format is like:

```
"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:NN:SS.ZZZ+XX:XX"  (i.e. "2009-03-24T16:24:32.057+01:00")
```

I have to do it in a ActionScript3 class but any source will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this related question:

[Actionscript 3 - Fastest way to parse yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to a Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163/actionscript-3-fastest-way-to-parse-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-to-a-date-object)

The accepted answer provides a way to parse an UTC time string to a `Date` object.

Answer (score 5):

```
\d{4}-[0-1]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-6]\d.\d{3}\+\d\d:\d\d
```

Or something similar?

More checks of the valid range are probably better done after the reg.ex.

Comment: You have an small typo: it should be "\d{4}-[0-1]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-6]\d.\d{3}\+\d\d:\d\d" (slash before +)

Answer (score 3):

Java regex, tested to read a date like `"2001-12-15T07:30:40Z"`:

```
"^\\d{4}-[0-1][0-3]-[0-3]\\d{1}T[0-2]\\d{1}:[0-5]\\d{1}:[0-5]\\d{1}Z$"
```

Comment: Single quote variant: `'^\d{4}-[0-1][0-3]-[0-3]\d{1}T[0-2]\d{1}:[0-5]\d{1}:[0-5]\d{1}Z$'`

Answer (score 1):

Following Regex is perfect for any UTC date formats

```
"^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\\.[0-9]+)?(Z)?$"
```

Ref: https://www.regexpal.com/94925

Answer (score 0):

Regex should be something like this:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\+\d{2}:\d{2}
```