# Javascript UTC match RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test if passed string is matching the following format (Thu, 08 Dec 2011 18:48:38 GMT), but I really suck in regular expressions. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: UTC is a time zone, not a format.

Comment: This is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/685377/675590

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: True, although "UTC string" does have meaning in the JavaScript arena: [`toUTCString`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.42) It's not a precise meaning, as it's completely implementation-dependent, but... :-)

Comment: Does this help? http://dotnetcaffe.blogspot.com/2009/12/javascript-utc-date-format.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the regular expression to test what you want:

```
var t = newDate();
/(Mon|Tue|...|Sun)\,\s\d{2}\s(Jan|Feb|...|Dec)\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\sGMT/.test(t.toUTCString())
```

of course you have to replace the ... with the remaining day and month names