# Need a regex expression to validate timestamp with utc

Tags: java, regex, datetime, timestamp, utc

I have a date format like :- `2014-08-17T14:07:30+0521` or `2015-05-21T14:07:30+0521`

Now I want to have a **regex expression** that can validate this date format..

I tried with the following format as given here [How to check an UTC formatted date with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685377/how-to-check-an-utc-formatted-date-with-a-regular-expression) :-

```
\d{4}-[0-1]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-6]\d:\d{3}\+\d\d:\d\d
```

but couldn't succeed ..
Since I am very new to this regex expression, I am finding it difficult to construct the expression that could validate successfully the **above** **timestamp** format with **utc**

Please note that, I want regex expression, other solution option will not work for me

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you particularly want to use a regex for this rather than just parsing it?

Comment: The last `:` in your regex seems out of place

Comment: Actually I have it in my request .. I have already parsed the request and I just need an expression to validate it

Comment: How do you define "validate"? Does this include verification of leap year rules i.e. validating if February 29th is okay for a given year? If you want this, too, then it becomes at least to say very hard with regular expressions.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Validate in the sence .. validating the format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following (the one you are using has different matching at the end):

```
\d{4}-[0-1]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\+\d{4}
```

**Edit:** In Java you can use the following:

```
\\d{4}-[0-1]\\d-[0-3]\\dT[0-2]\\d:[0-5]\\d:[0-5]\\d\\+\\d{4}
```

Comment: Thanks .. can you modify this without escape char \d and \+ ?

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary Check the update and.. why do you want it without escape chars?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\+\d{4}
```

Comment: Thanks .. can you modify this without escape char \d and \+ ?

Comment: replace the \d with [0-9]
the \+ you need because this is the regex for the character +

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the final solution I got using :-

```
\d{4}-[0-1]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\+\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ^((19|20)[0-9][0-9])[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[T]([01][1-9]|[2][0-3])[:]([0-5][0-9])[:]([0-5][0-9])([+|-]([01][0-9]|[2][0-3])[:]([0-5][0-9])){0,1}$
```

> 2018-11-11T11:01:59+11:11

https://www.regextester.com/100092